# Elastic Beanstalk - .ebextensions not running on deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a dotnet core application. And I'm packed it for docker.
My aim is deploying this application to EB but I need to run some commands after deploy.

Thats why I have created a **Dockerfile**

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
WORKDIR /

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY . ./App/
WORKDIR /App/WebApi
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /build --no-restore

WORKDIR /build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

And I have a **Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1"
}
```

And finally this is my **.ebextensions/01_nginx.conf**

```
commands: 
  test_command: 
    command: "touch /tmp/x.f"
```

Then I'm creating an EB application

```
$ eb init
```

and creating an enviorment

```
$eb create
```

It is deploying my application successfully.

**What is expected?**

When I login to my EC2 container with ssh I want to see the **/tmp/x.f** file.

**What is the problem?**

I have tried several ways, I'm sure that  **.ebextensions/01_nginx.conf** not running any way, because **/tmp/x.f** file not exists.

**Notes :**

- I'm sure that the zip file which is deployed has **.ebextensions/01_nginx.conf** file
- I'm sure that it is not about git. Because I'm including .ebignore in my root directory.
- I can react the end point without any problem, my application is deploying successfully.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probable reason is wrong extension of your files in `.ebextensions`. It [should](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) be `.config`, not `.conf`:

> Configuration files are YAML- or JSON-formatted documents with a **.config** file extension that you place in a folder named .ebextensions and deploy in your application source bundle.

Comment: Thank you. This is my mistake.